# Install PECL on windows 7

Tags: php, javascript, pecl, spidermonkey

can someone in this universe give me the step by step to install PECL for windows on php server, so then i can use the SpiderMonkey js engine to run js within php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the pecl4win site lacks due to limited resources. Pierre, our windows build master, creates extensions randomly on request and makes them available via http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ until the new PECL infrastructure is ready.

If you need an extension not available there you might ask on the pecl-dev at lists.php.net mailing list.

Also http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild has some instructions. The build system on windows currentlydoesn't allow building extensions stand-alone, but you have to build from the PHP source tree. For adding oauth you either have to put the sources under php-src/ext/oauth before running `buildconf.bat` or use the `--extra-ext-dir` (or similar) option for `buildconf.bat`.